# WPF ComboBox doesn't change the selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I'm a newbie in WPF, so it probably is something very basic that I'm forgetting to do but I can't see what it is.

I have a window with a combobox that display some data, I want the user to select a category in this combobox. It's working partially. The window show the combobox, starting with no selection, then the user choose a item, and it's set, but if the user try to change to other item, nothing works, it keeps the original selected item.

Here's me code:

**[Category class]**

```
public class Category {
    public long CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category MotherCategory { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public int Align { get; set; }
}
```

**[ComboBox XAML]**

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="motherCategoryComboBox" Margin="0,6,12,1"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <converter:LeftMarginConverter x:Key="LeftMarginConverter" />
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Categories}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="{Binding Path=Align, Converter={StaticResource LeftMarginConverter}}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

**[Window code-behind file]**

```
    public CategoryWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        db = new JaspeContext();
        categorieslist = db.Categories.ToList();

        motherCategoryComboBox.ItemsSource = categorieslist;

        Title = "Add category";
    }
```

**[The converter]**

```
public class LeftMarginConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double leftMargin = double.Parse(value.ToString());

        if (leftMargin != 1)
            leftMargin = leftMargin * 9;

        return new Thickness(leftMargin, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
    }
}
```

Need your help. This is making me crazy!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly. Is your DataContext a Category object? Sounds to me like you need to bind the `SelectedItem` property of the ComboBox.
E.g.:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="motherCategoryComboBox" Margin="0,6,12,1"
IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedItem="{Binding MotherCategory , Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

Comment: I don't set the DataContext, I pass a List<Category> direct to the ItemSource property of the combobox.

Comment: Sorry man, I accepted your answer, but I found that the origin of the behavior was more obscure. I've overriden the Equals method of Category and then it was causing strange things to happen in the combobox.

Comment: And ps: I want to kill myself.

Comment: Oops. Haha.. hope you're live n kickin' & managed to solve this by now!

Answer (score 0):

It's not your case but since it happened to me I'm publishing this here, to help other people who might stumble upon this issue...

During the `comboBox` `SelectionChangeCommitted()` event handler I added the following line:

```
combobox.Text = combobox.Text.Trim();
```

what it did is reset the `selectedIndex` and `selectedText` properties and didn't allow them to change to the new value due to keyboard or mouse input.

Comment: If you do this, wouldn't it affect the displayed result in the dropdown anytime you actually select it?